Applying Digital Beamforming to FMCW radar signal prior to extracting the Respiratoy Rate yields unexpected results
I am currently working on a university project where my goal is to extract the respiratory waveform from FMCW radar recordings. I use Infineons DEMO BGT60TR13C to record my data. For achieving that goal, I have picked the following paper and implemented the algorithm described in it. Now, the waveforms that I get by applying this algorithm in most cases are really close to my ground truth captured using a respiratory belt.
After successfully implementing the algorithm, my next step was to apply digital beamforming to specifically target the chest area only. The BGT60TR13C has 1 Tx antenna and 3 Rx antennas arranged in an L-shape to allow for digital beamforming. Infineon already has a Radar SDK that one can download where there is sample code for doing digital beamforming. Infineon has a document where digital beamforming is described. In short, beamforming there is done by multiplying the signal components with predefined weights depending on the antenna and angle. The weights are not mentioned in the document itself, however in the code snippets provided by Infineon they are computed by:
for iAntenna in range(num_antennas):
            weights[iAntenna, iBeam] = np.exp(
                1j * 2 * np.pi * iAntenna * d_by_lambda * np.sin(angle))

Finally, the beamforming is done according to (the following code is executed for each beam seperately and the accumulator variable is reset for each iteration):
for iAntenna in range(num_antennas):
            acc += range_doppler[:, :, iAntenna] * self.weights[num_antennas - iAntenna - 1, iBeam]
rd_beam_formed[:, :, iBeam] = acc

Now, Infineon uses the Range-Doppler Matrix for beamforming, while I only do a Range FFT before applying the beamforming. The results, at least for the azimuth direction, look correct. However, when I pick an angle or an angle range for which I do the beamforming, no matter what I pick, the respiratory waveform always looks very similar (and correct), even if I pick an angle where there should be absolutely no signal from my chest or body at all. Additionally, I have found the following paper, which seems to use the same weights for beamforming. What could have gone wrong on my side?
Best regards

TechnoX, without having additional information and some signal data to try out the beamforming, it's going to be difficult to get to the bottom of your issue.

You are probably right, here is a download link for sample data .
You can open it using:
with h5py.File(path_to_file, 'r') as file:     data = file['data'][:]
It should have a shape of (3, 64, 128, 600), representing the number of antennas, the number of chrips per frame, the number of samples per chirp and the number of frames. The data was recorded with a frame repetition time of 50 ms, so 600 frames equal 30 seconds. Furhtermore, the chrips start and end frequencies are 59_133_931_281 Hz and 62_366_068_720 Hz.

I really liked the idea of ​​using radar for monitoring respiratory function. Based on my experience in building radars with scanning arrays and after studying the footprint of the antenna arrangement on the printed circuit board of the microcircuit demonstrator, I realized that it is impossible to scan with a beam with such an arrangement of antennas. The easiest way to scan with a beam is to place the receiving antennas in one line with a distance between the centers in the range of 0.5-0.75 wavelengths. In this case, it will be possible to observe the beam swing by setting the phase coefficients of the receiving channels. To do this, you need to redesign the radar on a new printed circuit board. The problem is quite solvable. But I did not understand why scan with a beam? After all, the beam will not be narrow anyway. And the radar coverage area is a maximum of 15 meters.

You can beamform with any arrangement of antenna elements. It's just whether the patterns one forms have useful characteristics

I wouldn't say that the beam will be obtained with any amplitudes and phases. Here is a simple example that can be obtained on this breadboard. Set the amplitude coefficients for the channels AmRx1=1; AmRx2=0; AmRx3=1 and phases PhRx1=0 deg; PhRx=non; PhRx3=180 deg , then we get the directional diagram of this antenna array with two lobes turned to the sides and a dip in the direction of the orthogonal to the printed circuit board. And how will the radar work with two beams? Not any coefficients can be used for beamforming.

Unfortunately, I don't really understand what you mean here. Indeed, like you hinted, I use Rx 1 and 3 for azimuth. The two receive antennas have a distance of ~ 0.5*wavelength, like you mentioned above.  According to the Infineon document I posted in my first post, you can theoretically do digital beamforming with arbitrary precision (of course, the angle resoultion still depends on the number of receive antennas). The beamforming result itself, i.e. the heat map produced looks as expected, at least for the azimuth angles. The problem only occurrs when trying to extract the respiratory rate.
